# Photodiode circuit unstable measurements on MCU ADC

Tags: amplifier, adc, photodiode, transimpedance

I'm working on a fluoresce detection circuit.  I have a lot of unstable measurements on the output of my second amplifier with the ADC. With the multimeter I have stable measurements.

How can I smooth the readings for the ADC? And how do I eliminate the 60Hz noise that I see on my signal output?

[image]

[image: Scope reading of the output]

Comment: What do you mean with "unstable"? Fluctuations? Certain frequencies? What's the lightsource?

Comment: Try oversampling; store 10 successive samples then average them.

Comment: A lot of fluctuations, on the DMM is reading 500mV and the ADC readings values from 0V to 1.5V. The light source right now is ambient light.

Comment: You can connect a capacitor >= 10 uF parallel to R2 to form an integrator like the DMM has.

Comment: You say from IN- to OUT on IC2?

Comment: Does the 60 Hz signal go away if you cover the photodiode? Is the oscillation present on the output of the first stage amp?

Comment: @user1850479 The photodiode is inside a 3D printed case and just a fiber that goes inside it. The first stage amp has the same 60Hz noise

Comment: @user1850479 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fry3T.jpg

Comment: There are many issues: 1. X-Y problem: your question is why solution Y for problem X doesn't work, when it should be about problem X in the first place. 2. We have no idea what intensity or photocurrent, range, bandwidth, linearity, etc. is needed. 3. Why is testing with ambient light being done? It makes it seem as if the captured waveforms were intended; what else should you expect from random ambient sources? 4. Design of the optical system itself. Is it well sealed from ambient light? If not, why? 5. Is it shielded/filtered from the fluorescence stimulation source too?

Answer (score 2):

The DMM uses a dual-slope integration ADC method that rejects CM noise better and also has short probe cables.

Your ADC uses the Sample & Hold Method, (S&H) with a Successive Approximation Register (SAR) to measure both signal and noise in your cable which may be long, but is unknown.

What you need is to define your acceptable signal noise, Vn, f, and define your signal Vs, f then choose source impedance, cables, and filters to meet the resulting SNR you need.

It may be a simple fix but is an undefined problem.

Comment: don't add specs in comments pls.

Comment: How much noise to you think that the EVB connected via USB can cause to the amplifiers? Right now I user a external power supply with the ground connected to the EVB ground.